# Clash of Kings on One Plus 2 with OxgenOS 3.1.0 not responding error

Tags: oneplus-two, oxygenos

I have installed `clash of kings` game on my new android device which is one plus 2 and I just updated the `OxgenOS` to `3.1.0` and Clash of Kings stopped working,it always shows `not responding error` before upgrade it was working fine.

If anyone have faced same issue please help me. I have tried by reinstalling and clearing data but nothing worked.